# How to return the second non-blank cell from row excel for Mac

Tags: excel

To return the first non-blank cell in a row I use:

```
=INDEX(C1:F1,MATCH(TRUE,INDEX((C1:F1<>0),0),0))
```

However, how do you return the second non-blank cell in a row? I only have text in my cells.

When I attempt 
=INDEX(C1:F1,AGGREGATE(15,6,COLUMN(C1:F1)/SIGN(LEN(C1:F1)),2)), as suggested.

I don't get the next non-blank cell returned, I get F cell returned, even if there are others that should have been returned before it. If there is nothing in F, I get a 0.

Comment: `COLUMN($A:$D)` will give you the **position within** columns C:F.

Answer (score 3):

Use the [AGGREGATE function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/AGGREGATE-function-43B9278E-6AA7-4F17-92B6-E19993FA26DF)'s [SMALL subfunction](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/SMALL-function-4050a82e-659a-4ef6-a970-c963a6f69c29).

```
=INDEX(A1:A13, AGGREGATE(15, 6, ROW(1:13)/SIGN(LEN(A1:A13)), 2))
```

The *2* is the *k* for the small subfunction. Replace it with `ROW(2:2)` and tighten up all of the **other** cell references if you want to fill down for the third, fourth, etc.

[image: position_within]

When returning the column index number back to the [INDEX function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/index-function-0ee99cef-a811-4762-8cfb-a222dd31368a), [AGGREGATE function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/AGGREGATE-function-43B9278E-6AA7-4F17-92B6-E19993FA26DF) uses the [COLUMN function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/COLUMN-function-44E8C754-711C-4DF3-9DA4-47A55042554B) instead of the [ROW function](https://support.office.com/en-US/article/ROW-function-3A63B74A-C4D0-4093-B49A-E76EB49A6D8D).. `COLUMN($A:$D)` will give you the **position within** columns C:F; e.g. 1, 2, 3 or 4.

[image: position_within_columns]

Comment: I get a #Ref Error. If it helps, my cell contents are text and I am trying to identify the next non-blank cell in  row, not column.

Comment: As you can see from the added image, the formula works. I suspect that you modified the ranges fron your actual data to create the sample in your question. The `ROW($1:$13)` is the **position within** A1:A13, not the row on the worksheet. If your **actual** A1:A13 was A10:A19 then it would be `ROW($1:$10)` as that represents the **position within** A10:A19.

Comment: I think the Poster want to search a **row** rather than a **column**.

Comment: uh... ok, then change `ROW($1:$13)` to `COLUMN($A:$M)`.

Comment: @Jeeped I'm still not a massive fan of the use of ROW here, cf your comment in reply to the OP's comment. I can actually sympathasize with the OP here - why should they necessarily know to what to change the ROW portion depending on what range they are using? More to the point, you can use a construction for this part which is completely independent of the range being queried and so would not require any amendments to that extent.

Comment: Perhaps you could go back and [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/39374379/edit) your original question to **accurately** reflect what you are trying to do instead of adding tidbits into the various comments section(s) in an attempt to clarify what you are looking to accomplish.

Comment: @XORLX  *<sigh>* You are most likely right. Some who cannot grasp that even the common [MATCH](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/match-function-0600e189-9f3c-4e4f-98c1-943a0eb427ca) produces the numerical  **position within** a range of cells referenced by the [INDEX](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/index-function-0ee99cef-a811-4762-8cfb-a222dd31368a) function probably shouldn't be learning this as rudimentary concept. That should be understood by anyone attempting to match/return from one place to another. Shovelling in a 'turn-key' formula without understanding helps no one.

Answer (score 2):

```
{=INDEX(C1:F1, SMALL(IF(C1:F1 <> "", COLUMN(C1:F1) - 2), 2))}
```

https://exceljet.net/formula/get-nth-match-with-index-match

`-2` is from `-COLUMN(INDEX(C1:F1, 1, 1)) + 1` so the full array formula is:

```
{=INDEX(C1:F1, SMALL(IF(C1:F1<>"", COLUMN(C1:F1) - COLUMN(INDEX(C1:F1, 1, 1)) + 1), 2))}
```

Comment: tbpf, if I am catching flack for using `COLUMN(A:D)` to represent `1, 2, 3, 4` then you should explain the mathematical adjustment in `COLUMN(C1:F1)-2),2`. Same 'playing field' and all that nonsense.

Comment: @Jeeped it was a last minute fix because I used `A1:F1` when I posted the answer and then me being lazy like usual :] I was curious what the answer would be pre-2010 as I am still using Excel 2007 but I found your answer very informative as `AGGREGATE`'s ignoring errors and hidden cells seems very useful.