# Avoiding INDIRECT()

Tags: excel

I have data in row #3 like:

[image]

and I want to locate the first two occurrences of the word *Pass*.

The first occurrence is easy; in **C6** I enter:

```
=MATCH("Pass",3:3,0)
```

and it correctly yields 3 *(Column **C**)*.  To get the position of the second occurrence, I want to use MATCH() starting one column to the right of the first occurrence, that is **D3:IV3**, but based on the result I already have in **C6** 
I know I can get the **D** with:

```
=SUBSTITUTE((LEFT(ADDRESS(1,C6+1),3)),"$","")
```

So I am using:

```
=MATCH("Pass",INDIRECT(SUBSTITUTE((LEFT(ADDRESS(1,C6+1),3)),"$","") & "3:IV3"),0)+C6
```

This works:

[image]

But I can't believe that this extremely ugly formula is the best way to find the second occurrence.  Any suggestions ??

Comment: See [How to return the second non-blank cell from row](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39374379/how-to-return-the-second-non-blank-cell-from-row-excel-for-mac/39374473#39374473) from earlier today.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use AGGREGATE as a SMALL(IF()) to get the second column with `Pass`:

```
=AGGREGATE(15,6,COLUMN(A:Z)/(A3:Z3="Pass"),2)
```

Where `2` is the occurrence.

[image]

---

I know how much you dislike array formulas so since you already know the first you can find the second with this formula:

```
=MATCH("Pass",INDEX(3:3,D5+1):INDEX(3:3,15000),0)+D5
```

[image: ![enter image description here]

Comment: @Gary'sStudent I edited the post (again) to use your helper cell with the first instance, thus avoiding the array formula.