# Excel, How to use average with indirect?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, average, cells, excel-indirect

I've been trying to use AVERAGE with INDIRECT but keeps giving me errors.

Now I am using Average like this: 
    `AVERAGE(Results!C2:C51)`
I need to get data from another sheet "Results". But in my current sheet I got the range of the rows set in two cells.

```
+-------------------+
|    ...  E   F     |
|   +-------+-------+
| 2 |...| 2 | 51|   |
|   +---------------+
| 3 |   | 52|101|   |
|   +---------------+
| 4 |   |   |   |   |
+---+---+---+---+---+
```

I've tried like this, but it's not working:

```
AVERAGE(Results!INDIRECT("C"&E2):INDIRECT("C"&F2))
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should do it:

```
=AVERAGE(INDIRECT("Results!C"&E2&":C"&F2))
```

Answer (score 1):

The answer posted by zipa is correct.  Here is an alternaive that will allow you to avoid *INDIRECT()* entirely:

```
=AVERAGE(INDEX(Results!C:C,E2):INDEX(Results!C:C,F2))
```

[image]

This is based on [Scott Craner's Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39378485/avoiding-indirect) to a question I asked previously.